I am unable to fail the Jenkins pipeline based on Sonar results
I am new to groovy. I am using Jenkins scripted pipeline. It's a gradle project. We are using the library in our Jenkinsfile. Basically, I want to fail the pipeline based on Sonar results. Below is the library code that I import in my Jenkinsfile. By default, stopOnFailure:false. I should make it as true to fail the pipeline. How do I pass this argument in my Jenkinsfile.
Note: I am not allowed to make any changes to my library
Filename: sonarqube.groovy
def scan(Map args=[stopOnFailure:false, waitForCompletion:true], Closure closure) {
   closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
   withEnv(["JAVA_HOME=${tool 'JDK 11'}"]) {
      withEnv(["PATH+SONARSCANNER=${tool 'SonarQube Scanner'}/bin"]) {
         withSonarQubeEnv('CICD Sonarqube') {
            closure()
            env.SONARQUBE_URL = env.SONAR_HOST_URL
         }

         if (args.waitForCompletion == true) {
            sleep 5
            timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') { // Just in case something goes wrong, pipeline will be killed after a timeout
               def qg = waitForQualityGate() // Reuse taskId previously collected by withSonarQubeEnv
               if ((args.stopOnFailure == true) && (qg.status != 'OK')) {
                  error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

My Jenkinsfile.groovy(scripted pipeline)
                    stage('CodeQuality') {
                        withEnv(["SONAR_USER_HOME=${WORKSPACE}/.sonar"]) {
                            withSonarQubeEnv {
                                sh "./gradlew sonarqube"
                            }
                        }
                    }


How do you import the library code? Is it a Jenkins shared library that you import with @Library? Or is it something in gradle that you don't really import in your jenkinsfile, just interact with by calling through the sh step??

Looks like that scan method is called inside gradle and not directly in jenkins.  So you'll need to modify gradle build.gradle file to get it to work.  It looks like this might be a task type possibly.  But, just regular groovy it would look like this:
scan( stopOnFailure:true, waitForCompletion:true) {  /* configure the task here */ }

@chubbsondubs: I tried your way of using the scan and also modified the library a bit but it gets stuck at the timeout line.

Hmm.  Well is the scan finished when it gets stuck on the timeout line?  That line will wait for 1 hour before giving up on the waitForQualityGate().  If that doesn't finish it will hang for 1 hour then throw an exception after 1 hour.  Big question is did gradle finish it's task?  If not it's probably stuck on the scan.  You might try running a scan manual outside of Jenkins before doing it in Jenkins.  At least you'd know if there is something wrong inside your gradle build before trying to figure it out from within Jenkins.
